# Need to read text between certain characters in a text file C++

Tags: c++, line, symbols

So I have a text file called Names.txt which has 20 000 lines.
Example of a line looks like this

```
"niineve","1 Mo.","VT","1 Mo. 10:12"
"nimrod","1 Mo.","VT","1 Mo. 10:8"
"nimrod","1 Mo.","VT","1 Mo. 10:9"
"noa","1 Mo.","VT","1 Mo. 5:29"
```

Just FYI At the moment I have a code in which I can input a name and find how many times does it appear in a file.

Now I need to somehow get the Mo part to output, I have tons of syllables in file like "Ilm.", "Mo.", "Sj.", "Sk." and I need to get a necessary one to output but I won't go too specific at the moment.

MY QUESTION: Is there a way to get the characters from a line starting from first capital letter (included) and ending with first period (excluded).

So if my line in a text file would be

```
"hiskija","2 Ku.","VT","2 Ku. 20:8"
```

then output would be Ku since K is first capital letter and after Ku comes a period.
If not can you suggest an another way how I can get a syllable (2-3 characters) from that spot, I thought that maybe I could get from between symbols "," and . so if the lines was

```
"niineve","1 Mo.","VT","1 Mo. 10:12"
```

I'd get output of 1 Mo but I haven't had experience with any commands which could do it.

EDIT: This is what I have at the moment

```
ifstream file ("Names.txt");

int i;
for (i = 0; i < book.length(); ++i) {
    if ('A' <= book[i] && book[i] <= 'Z') break;
}

string start = book.substr(i);
getline(file, start, '.');
cout << start;
```

With that it successfully reads from beginning of a line until first period "." but I have not managed to put the starting point to the first capital letter. I think I haven't declared i and string start correctly.

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working? As a starting point - file parsers generally tend to be large [state machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Perhaps turning this into a state machine may help your thought process - the programming from there is simply the semantics of the language.

Comment: Mm sorry, I have been searching a bit and this seemed like a good place to start. I found scanf function but it always seems to be with printf. Do you know if there's equivalent to scanf in C++ which goes with cout? And how would one determine a capital letter in scanf function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read data up to a certain character with a getline function

```
getline(file,str,delimiter);
```

which will write the everything in the string 'str' until the delimiter ('.' in your case) is found.

then you only have to iterate throught the string and find the first capital letter, like

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
    if ('A' <= str[i] && str[i] <= 'Z') break;
}
```

the variable 'i' now holds the starting index, and all you have to do now is extract the appropriate substing

```
str.substr(i) // from 'i' all the way to the end
```

Comment: I managed to get it half working with your help, can you please check my EDIT under main question to help with the current problem in that.

Comment: you have all the code there, it'st just in the wrong order.
make file.
declare emprty string book.
read file with getline into book.
then the for loop.
then cout << book.substr(i) << endl;